# Custom Value Accessor With Datepicker in angular

Tags: angular

How to use the datepicker in customvalueaccessor.

**CODE SAMPLE**

```
<mat-form-field>
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [disabled]="disabled" (blur)="onTouched()"  (input)="onChange($event.target.value)" [value]="value" placeholder="Choose a date" >

<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

onchange is not working.
Value got changed only on the input. If I use datepicker values are not changing

Comment: Did you implement customValueAccessor interface to your class?

Answer (score 0):

Try with reactive forms:

```
<mat-form-field>
 <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [disabled]="disabled" (blur)="onTouched()"  
 formControlName="pickerDate" placeholder="Choose a date" >

 <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

on your ts file:

```
this.searchDate = this.formBuilder.group({
  pickerDate: this.pickerDate
});
```